# Excel if else formula fails due to wrong syntex

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have different class name in excel column in character form. I want to convert it to numerical form and add in column C

```
If B2==N, make it 1
If B2==O, make it 0
If B2==A, make it 2
If B2==~, make it 9
```

I have written the following excel formula. I have added my formula and error message in image. Can you correct me where I am making mistake

```
=IF(B2='N',1,if(b2='O',0,if(b2='A',2,if(b2='~',9))))
```

[image]

Update

After adding the formula as per details answer

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within **Excel formulas**, **double quotes** are used to denote the **start** and **end of a text string**. Numeric should not be within double quotes.

That said, we can use a formula like `IF` function but we can also avoid using **double quotes** by creating a table of reference, refer the image below, for alternative solutions - **7 APPROACHES**

• Formula used in cell **C2**

```
=VLOOKUP($B2,$I$2:$J$5,2,1)
```

Without **Table Of Reference** the above formula can be written as

```
=VLOOKUP($B2,{"~",9;"A",2;"N",1;"O",0},2,1)
```

• Formula used in cell **D2**

```
=LOOKUP($B2,$I$2:$J$5)
```

Without **Table Of Reference** the above formula can be written as

```
=LOOKUP($B2,{"~",9;"A",2;"N",1;"O",0})
```

• Formula used in cell **E2** --> "Correction To Your Own Formula"

```
=IF(B2="N",1,IF(B2="O",0,IF(B2="A",2,IF(B2="~",9))))
```

• Formula used in cell **F2**

```
=IFS(B2="~",9,B2="A",2,B2="N",1,B2="O",0)
```

• Formula used in cell **G2**

```
=SWITCH($B2,"~",9,"A",2,"N",1,"O",0)
```

Note the formulas used in cell **F2** & **G2** you need to have either **Excel 2019, Excel 2021 Or O365** hence its better to use a **Table Of Reference** to avoid using **Double Quotes**.

[image: 7_APPROACHES]

So, if there is a space before each characters then the formula, shall change refer the image below and & the formulas,

• Formula used in cell **C2**

```
=VLOOKUP(TRIM($B2),$I$2:$J$5,2,1)
```

• Formula used in cell **D2**

```
=LOOKUP(TRIM($B2),$I$2:$J$5)
```

• Formula used in cell **E2**

```
=IF(TRIM($B2)="N",1,IF(TRIM($B2)="O",0,IF(TRIM($B2)="A",2,IF(TRIM($B2)="~",9))))
```

• Formula used in cell **F2**

```
=IFS(TRIM($B2)="~",9,TRIM($B2)="A",2,TRIM($B2)="N",1,TRIM($B2)="O",0)
```

• Formula used in cell **G2**

```
=SWITCH(TRIM($B2),"~",9,"A",2,"N",1,"O",0)
```

And if those are not spaces and actually are non printable characters then just change the `TRIM` to `SUBSTITUTE` Function

**C2**

```
=VLOOKUP(SUBSTITUTE($B2,CHAR(160),""),$I$2:$J$5,2,1)
```

**D2**

```
=LOOKUP(SUBSTITUTE($B2,CHAR(160),""),$I$2:$J$5)
```

**E2**

```
=IF(SUBSTITUTE($B2,CHAR(160),"")="N",1,IF(SUBSTITUTE($B2,CHAR(160),"")="O",0,IF(SUBSTITUTE($B2,CHAR(160),"")="A",2,IF(SUBSTITUTE($B2,CHAR(160),"")="~",9))))
```

**F2**

```
=IFS(SUBSTITUTE($B2,CHAR(160),"")="~",9,SUBSTITUTE($B2,CHAR(160),"")="A",2,SUBSTITUTE($B2,CHAR(160),"")="N",1,SUBSTITUTE($B2,CHAR(160),"")="O",0)
```

**G2**

```
=SWITCH(SUBSTITUTE($B2,CHAR(160),""),"~",9,"A",2,"N",1,"O",0)
```

[image: BLANKS]

Comment: Thanks really appreciate, but there seems something wrong at my side, None of above formula working. I have updated the description can you please check whats wonrg

Comment: @user3449212 there is space before each characters in column B, so you need to wrap the cell with `TRIM` alright. let me edit my query for you!

Comment: @user3449212 try now using either with `TRIM` or `SUBSTITUTE` Function and let me know!

Comment: @user3449212 refer I have edited the solutions again, there may be spaces or non printable characters hence formulas provided accordingly refer above

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would do something like this, using `IFS` function:

```
=IFS(B2="N",1,B2="O",0,B2="A",2,B2="~",9)
```

Comment: It gives #N/A as a result

Comment: @user3449212 did you check the alternatives I have provided. And I believe there is a space before the Class Types, therefore the formula will be like this `=IFS(TRIM(B2)="~",9,TRIM(B2)="A",2,TRIM(B2)="N",1,TRIM(B2)="O",0)` unless there are non printable characters!

Answer (score 1):

In Excel, double quotes is used to enclose character values not single quote. Hence, your formula will become

`=IF(B2="N",1,IF(B2="O",0,IF(B2="A",2,IF(B2="~",9,""))))`

Additionally, I have added an else clause with blanks in last IF.

Also, if you are on newer versions of Excel, then you can also use SWITCH which is easier and shorter

`=SWITCH(B2,"N",1,"O",0,"A",2,"~",9,"")`